# Failing to Access Outlet Context in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

Okay so I have scoured the internet for an example of how to do this but unfortunately I am not able to do so. Basically I have a componenet structure like this:

**App.js**

```
class App extends Componenent {
  render() {
     return (
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/signin' exact element={<SignIn />} />
          <Route path='/admin' exact element={<Admin />} >
             <Route path='home' exact element={<Home/>} />
             <Route path='settings' exact element={<Settings/>} />
        </Route >
     );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**admin.jsx**

```
import { useLocation, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const Admin = props => {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <div>
       <p>Parent</p>
       <div>
          <Outlet context={'foo'} />
       </div>
    </div>
}

export default Admin;
```

**settings.jsx**

```
import React from "react";

const Settings = props => {
  const context = useOutletContext();
  console.log(context);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
       <p>settings</p>
    </React.Fragment>
}

export default Settings;
```

However, each time I load the page, I get a an error that says exactly:

```
'useOutletContext' is not defined  no-undef
```

and the app crashes. However, when I look at my componenet tree with the chrome react debug panel, the context is there in the outlet, I just don't know how to access it. Here are some screenshots so that we are on the same page:

**Context is in the outlet**
[image]

**The same data is in the Context.Provider as "value" now**
[image]

**Nowhere to be seen in the Route.Provider**
[image]

**Nowhere to be seen in the Settings Componenet**
[image]

Any and all help here would be appreciated, I am just not entirely sure of how to use `useOuletContext();` even if I used followed the steps in the [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useoutletcontext). Do I have to import it from somewhere? Does it have to be in the same file for it to work?

Comment: I was also surprised to see the import path is never mentioned in the docs. I always try to find a reference to the import directly in the docs so I know for sure my path is correct. Seems like it should be included. `import { useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom'`

Comment: @BrianThompson It wouldn't be the first time I've seen something missing or incorrect in the RRDv6 docs; I've opened PRs to update other parts of the READMEs. I do see that the docs for the other various RRDv6 hooks show the import as part of an example.

Comment: Indeed it is, @Drew Reese answered that the import is supposed to be from 'react-router-dom'

Comment: [PR](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/pull/8668) to update docs if you cared to follow along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it still needs to be imported in the file using it, i.e. `import { useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';`.

```
import React from "react";
import { useOutletContext } from 'react-router-dom';

const Settings = props => {
  const context = useOutletContext();
  console.log(context);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
       <p>settings</p>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Settings;
```

Comment: Wow, the solution was really that simple and I spent a proverbial millenium on this. Thank you very much for that clarification. I couldn't seem to find it anywhere